# What is the best way for Merging same items in a listView?

Tags: android, algorithm, listview, arraylist

I have a `lisView` with some items that may have a similar property, I want:

**first**, found these items that have similar property.

**second**, Merge these into one row item of list view,

and

**finally**, when item selected ,show their items ( that are merged ) in a layout that expands.

my idea is not so strong, I want to use `for` loop to found similar items, then store them in an `array` and finally in `adapter` check that if item is a merged `type` then use `Expandable Layout`.

***Is any better solution?***

Answer (score 1):

Consider using HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>();
```

Where your property is string or anything that can be compared, and as value it will store list of your items. To do so use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems.size(); i++) {
        if(map.containsKey(listOfItems.get(i).property){
          map.get(listOfItems.get(i).property).add(listOfItems.get(i));
        }else{
          ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
          temp.add(listOfItems.get(i);
          map.put(listOfItems.get(i).property, listOfItems.get(i))
       }
    }
```

And to get list of object with this same property use

```
map.get(property)
```